# How to manage Mysql YEAR type with doctrine 2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I need a field for store only a year, not a complete date. Can I manage mysql YEAR type with doctrine 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That mapping doesn't currently exist. You will have to use a string or a date field. Or create you own mapping. I don't know the exact steps needed. But these references can hopefully help.

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#custom-mapping-types

Comment: yep it will be converted to dateTime object and in the template you will have to do  |date("Y")

Answer (score 0):

I tried it and work fine:

```
/**
 * @var \Year
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="year_born", columnDefinition="YEAR", nullable=false)
 */
private $yearBorn;
```

Comment: Surely this var won't be of type \Year but string? You should create custom mapping for that.